# Precise statement of Weyl's unitary trick?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, invariant-theory

Let $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$ be representations of $SL(2)$. Given arbitrary $f:V \to \mathbb{R}$, is it possible to construct an "averaged" function such that for all $g \in SL(2, \mathbb{R})$, $\tilde{f}(\rho_1(g) x) = \rho_2(g) \tilde{f}(x)$, along the lines of $$ \tilde{f}(x) = \int_{h\in SO(2)} f(\rho_1(h)x) dh?$$

Given the end of the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3971068/993547), I would infer something like the above is true, where one only needs to integrate over the maximally compact subgroup. However, the computation above does not seem to be correct computationally. What exactly is the Theorem statement of Weyl's unitary trick in this context?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I did not say the right thing there. I thought I knew what the correct statement was but I've managed to confuse myself so I'm going to delete my answer for now and try to figure out the correct statement.

Comment: In the meantime here's a link to an accurate description of the unitary trick: https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/021/12/1073-1091